# In Azure DevOps, is there a way to list all work items by developer assigned to and sprint in a grid view?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, is there a way to get a view that looks something like this, showing all work items scheduled for them in sprints?

Example:

```
Developer  | Sprint 1 | Sprint 2     | Sprint 3
John       | US123    | US124, US125 | None
Steve      | None     | None         | US126
Adam       | US127    | US128        | None
```

So far in Azure DevOps, the closest view that I have found is the Feature Timeline plugin from Microsoft here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.workitem-feature-timeline-extension&ssr=false#overview

Answer (score 1):

There is no directory to get the report as above example. You can create a query to export workitems to a .csv file. And then do the necessary operations (group, filter,etc.) in the csv file. Please refer to below steps.

1, Create a query. Boards-->Queries-->New Query

Edit your query filters to query all the User Story work item, Then click  **Column options** to select what fields to display in the query results.

Then click the **3dot**(...) and select **Export to csv**

[image]

When you get the .csv file, you can modify the file. For example create a simple pivotTable like below screenshot.

[image]

Another possible way is to use PowerBI to generate a report from the workitems.

You can check the sample PowerBI reports [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-rollup?view=azure-devops&tabs=odata). Check the PowerBI sample query [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/wit-analytics?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something built into the software, or a plugin that does the same. I guess it does not exist.

Comment: There is no existing plugins I can find. the easiest way to achieve a similar result i found is to use excel. I belive PowerBI can achieve such a report, but it need to write some Power BI Query.